# Eloqua replacing <script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, eloqua

for anyone using Eloqua I am having an issue. I have been told multiple times on topliners/calling support that I am able to use external javascript by linking it. I am having an issue though. My code is as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mcgilvraydesign.com/parkertest/script.js"></script>
```

It looks correct when I upload it into Eloqua using their HTML uploader, but when I preview the landing page it replaces any script tag with the following

```
<span class="eloquasanitized" id="3748dc6a-318a-4bec-a860-44c810d1c6d9" display="none"></span>
```

Have any of you who have used Eloqua had a similar issue?

All responses are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is Eloqua Generated ID for that "script.js" link while after uploaded it into Eloqua Instance.

In my eDM I have added the Facebook link and saved it.Then I view href link code, it will generated with eloqua Generated ID.I have send a test mail to myself and checked,its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try editing the code after uploading?

Like replace the `<span>`with the `<scirpt>`tag.